# Typeorm update partial jsonb them other field get zero value

Tags: node.js, typeorm, nest

I have a table for plans and there is a jsonb field `data` that have some keys. but when I was update this field other field going to be get a zero value like that:

```js
export interface PlanData {
  [key: string]: any;
}

@Entity({ name: 'Plans' })
export class Plan {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @Column({ unique: true })
  name: string;

  @Column('jsonb', { nullable: false, default: {} })
  data: PlanData;

  @CreateDateColumn({
    type: 'timestamptz',
    default: () => 'current_timestamp',
    name: 'createdAt',
  })
  createdAt: Date;

  @UpdateDateColumn({
    type: 'timestamptz',
    default: () => 'current_timestamp',
    name: 'updatedAt',
  })
  updatedAt: Date;
}
```

for update:

```js
 async update(planId: string, updatePlanRequest: Partial<Plan>): Promise<any> {
    return this.planRepository.update(
      { id: planId },
      { data: updatePlanRequest.data },
    );
  }
```

and update dto:

```js
export class PlanDataDto {
  @IsOptional()
  @IsNumber()
  unitCost?: number;

  @IsOptional()
  @IsArray()
  extension?: string[];

  @IsOptional()
  @IsNumber()
  unitDivision?: number;

  @IsOptional()
  @IsNumber()
  audioSizeLimit?: number;

  @IsOptional()
  @IsNumber()
  balanceWarning?: number;

  @IsOptional()
  @IsString()
  apiKeyExpireTime?: string;

  @IsOptional()
  @IsNumber()
  audioDurationLimit?: number;

  @IsOptional()
  @IsNumber()
  defaultWalletBalance?: number;
}
```

and after that I get

```json
    "id": "86ab55b4-07d3-4acc-a00b-af9d2f273b83",
    "name": "default2۲۵48۹2",
    "data": {
        "extension": [],
        "unitCost": 0,
        "unitDivision": 0,
        "audioSizeLimit": 0,
        "balanceWarning": 20000,
        "apiKeyExpireTime": "",
        "audioDurationLimit": 0,
        "defaultWalletBalance": 0
    },
    "createdAt": "2023-09-18T02:06:17.494Z",
    "updatedAt": "2023-09-18T02:48:20.312Z"
```